# Error: Cannot find module; Typescript error in react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, package.json

I have a .js file called load_routes.js file in the node_express folder. This load_routes.js file loads all my routes for the project. I have a package.json file in which the load_routes.js is used to load the routes. So, this part was working fine, until I changed the file extension of load_routes.js file to .ts file. I started getting

```
Error: Cannot find module '/*****/***/****/****/****/node_express/load_routes.ts'
```

I have not changed the location of the files. And the node_express folder is a sibling or present at the same level as that of package.json file.

package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build && echo \"const version='$(git rev-parse HEAD)'; module.exports=version\" > ./node_express/version/release-version.js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "NODE_ENV=localhost PORT=**** node --max-http-header-size 81000 ./node_express/load_routes.ts",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
  },
```

Can someone help me with this. The file load_routes.ts is for sure there. The path to that file seems correct as it worked when it was a .js file. Why do I get this error? I am stuck on this for quite some time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the file extension at all. The `require` call will figure out the right file automatically.